# Join object values in Array.map

Tags: javascript

```
const rules = transposed
  .slice(1)
  .map(
    ([
      sourceSystem,
      classification1, classification2, classification3, classification4,
      segment,
      calendar,
      createSla,
      slaDurationInMinutes,
      sendNotification,
      useHolidays,
    ]: any) => ({
      calendar,
      // classification: 'ABC, DEF',
      classification1,
      classification2,
      classification3,
      classification4,
      createSla,
      segment,
      sendNotification,
      slaDurationInMinutes,
      sourceSystem,
    }),
  );
```

How can I join the string values of classification1...4 like

`classification: classification1 + classification2 + classification3 + classification4`?

The result should be `classifications: "ABC,DEF,XYZ,PEF"`

Comment: Your "like" example is *almost* literally how you would do it, unless there are other constraints you haven't mentioned (such as some of them being optional/possibly blank, etc.). What specific issue did you have doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "like" example is *almost* literally how you would do it, unless there are other constraints you haven't mentioned (such as some of them being optional/possibly blank, etc.):

```
const rules = transposed
  .slice(1)
  .map(
    ([
      sourceSystem,
      classification1, classification2, classification3, classification4,
      segment,
      calendar,
      createSla,
      slaDurationInMinutes,
      sendNotification,
      useHolidays,
    ]: any) => ({
      calendar,
      classification: classification1 + "," + classification2 + "," + classification3 + "," + classification4, // ***
      createSla,
      segment,
      sendNotification,
      slaDurationInMinutes,
      sourceSystem,
    }),
  );
```

(Or with a template literal as [shown by Nenad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68454738/157247).)

If some of them may be blank and you want to skip those, you might create and filter an array, then use `.join(",")` to join the values:

```
const rules = transposed
  .slice(1)
  .map(
    ([
      sourceSystem,
      classification1, classification2, classification3, classification4,
      segment,
      calendar,
      createSla,
      slaDurationInMinutes,
      sendNotification,
      useHolidays,
    ]: any) => ({
      calendar,
      classification: [classification1, classification2, classification3, classification4].filter(c => !!c).join(",")
      createSla,
      segment,
      sendNotification,
      slaDurationInMinutes,
      sourceSystem,
    }),
  );
```

*(Yes, `.filter(c => !!c)` could be just `.filter(c => c)` or `.filter(Boolean)`. I write what seems clear to me and let the minifier worry about minifying. :-) )*

Answer (score 2):

Try simply with template literals:

```
const rules = transposed
  .slice(1)
  .map(
    ([
      sourceSystem,
      classification1, classification2, classification3, classification4,
      segment,
      calendar,
      createSla,
      slaDurationInMinutes,
      sendNotification,
      useHolidays,
    ]: any) => {
    return {
      calendar,
      classification: `${classification1},${classification2},${classification3},${classification4}`,
      createSla,
      segment,
      sendNotification,
      slaDurationInMinutes,
      sourceSystem
    }
  });
```